# How to password protect an application process

Tags: windows, passwords

Can somebody tell me how to protect an application using password.

I mean suppose I start an application (say uTorrent) then I want to provide a password so that nobody can close it or change any thing without password.

Thanks

Ashwani

Answer (score 2):

Use Windows Switch User and let others to use less privilege account. Once you run your programs under your account, others can't access it.

This question belongs to superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is not possible to protect an application (as normal user) in a way that prevents closing (by an administrator).
All other stuff is handled by the windows user system. Just lock your user session...

Or please describe your real problem.

Comment: Thanks Tuergeist:

I want to protect any application which is icon tray. If I start an application it should ask for password, and once it is minimized to icon tray, it should ask for a password to come in focus.

And if somebody tries to stop the process the application using the task manager, then it should ask for password. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see any possibility to solve your problem except that you use different users.